# Audio Metering with LibVLC

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, libvlc

I'm using LibVLC in a Windows C++ application to display a video stream.

I want to monitor the incoming audio samples to generate metering data passed to another part of my application. I have this sort-of working with `libvlc_audio_set_callbacks` except a: I'm monitoring the output audio, so it's affected by mutes,etc and b: When I enable this, the audio can't be heard (admittedly, this is the behaviour described in the documentation).

Is there a way of actually doing this with the LibVLC API, or do I need to write an audio filter plugin?

Alternatively, Is there some existing generic 'audio sniffing' plugin that I could use?

Comment: If you can live with a Windows-only solution, you might want to look into [Audio Mixers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742869.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, but I need to be able to work with audio from network streams. :(

Comment: You may want to take a look at the provided modules. There's a lot of core modules that are included. That said implementing a module isn't overly difficult. See the [audio bar graph](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/modules/audio_filter/audiobargraph_a.c) module for an example. (The [float mixer](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/modules/audio_mixer/float.c) would also be a good place to look.)

Comment: @theB I looked at the audio bar graph filter which is interesting. But I can't work out how libVLC-based code can call (for example) ` var_AddCallback(vlcInstance, "audiobargraph_v-i_values",...)`. What should I pass as the first parameter?

Comment: Check out https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial/ which shows creating an instance.

Comment: @theB I'm creating the libVLC instance fine - but the problem is trying to call var_AddCallback, which seem to require a VLC_OBJECT. How to go from a libvlc_instance_t to a VLC_OBJECT? I'm just getting AV's...

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. Id have to dig in to see how the core module loader is actually initializing the modules/plugins in the first place. If I crack it I'll post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit late for a response but this is a question that I had difficulty struggling through and others may be in the same place (even if the OP has long since moved on!).

The key is to use the `smem` plugin.  This lets you track audio and video as it is being played (with some serious caveats, see below).  In order to play and meter at the same time, you need to `duplicate` the stream (split it).  Below is the output string to use to do so:

```
std::ostringstream outstream;
outstream << ":sout=#duplicate{dst=std{access=file,dst=\"" << filepath << "\"},dst=\"transcode{acodec=s16l}:" << createFrameCallbackString(true) << "\"}";
libvlc_media_add_option(media, outstream.str().c_str());
```

We need to create an output chain in which the stream is split, thus the call to `duplicate`. Within duplicate, there are two destinations.

```
outstream << ":sout=#duplicate{dst=...,dst=...}";
```

In my example I'm recording to file (rather than displaying to a video window) so you would want to replace the first destination with your own.
The second destination is where we are sending the audio (and/or video) to callback methods using `smem`:

```
"..., dst=\"transcode{acodec=s16l}:" << createFrameCallbackString(true) << "\"}"
```

Note about audio in smem, it has to be in PCM (or so it seems by the documentation), and so we transcode it to signed 16 bit little endian (s16l) (that's an L at the end, not a 1).
What is the overhead cost of the transcoding?  In my tests it seems to be pretty small, but if you have performance concerns it's worth looking at.

Configuring the output chain for smem is as follows:

```
class Player
{
//callback for frame monitoring
static void prerendercb(void *data, unsigned char** buffer, size_t size)
{
    //we must allocate a buffer in order for postrender to be called
    *buffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(size);
}

static void postrendercb(void *data, unsigned char* buffer, int width, int height, int pitch, size_t size, int64_t pts)
{
    Player* context = (Player*)data;
    //free the buffer
    free(buffer);
    //notify context of frame for processing
    context->OnFrame(/*pass it whatever information you need*/);
}
static void audio_prerendercb(void* data, unsigned char** buffer, size_t size)
{
    *buffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(size);
}
static void audio_postrendercb(void* data, unsigned char* buffer, unsigned int channels, unsigned int rate, 
        unsigned int nb_samples, unsigned int bits_per_sample, size_t size, int64_t pts)
{
    Player* context = (Player*)data;
    //free the buffer
    free(buffer);
    //notify context
    context->OnAudioFrame(/*whatever data is needed*/);
}

//Get an smem string for the audio/video callbacks
std::string Player::createFrameCallbackString(bool timesync) const
{
    std::ostringstream text;
    text <<
        "smem{" << "video-prerender-callback=" << ((long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)&prerendercb) << "," <<
                       "video-postrender-callback=" << ((long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)&postrendercb) << "," <<
                       "video-data=" << ((long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)this) << "," <<
                       "audio-prerender-callback=" << ((long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)&audio_prerendercb) << "," <<
                       "audio-postrender-callback=" << ((long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)&audio_postrendercb) << "," <<
                       "audio-data=" << ((long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)this) << "," <<
                       "time-sync=" << (timesync ? "1" : "0") <<
                       "}";

    return text.str();
}

}
```

**Caveats**
Aside from the transcoding issue, and the fact that you have to allocate the buffer data whether you care about it or not, the biggest issue is that libVLC processes frames **asynchronously**.  As a result you will tend to get bursts where 10, 15 frames get processed all at once and then you won't see anything for a while, then another burst.  This definitely affected by the cache sizes (there are several in libVLC) but even setting the cache sizes as low as possible, you will still get bursts at least of 2 or 3 frames.
Setting these options helps a lot:

```
libvlc_media_add_option(media, ":clock-synchro=0"); //this setting is critical for realtime processing of audio stream!
libvlc_media_add_option(media, ":clock-jitter=0");
```

Another caveat when constructing your output chain is to pay attention to quotes and brackets. There may be guidelines published somewhere but for me it was a bit of trial and error.

Finally, I have never noticed a reasonable difference when using `time-sync` option in `smem`.  I'm sure it matters what it is set to, but I was unable to determine how.

What I've found in using libVLC is that it's not really made for this kind of use.  It can be twisted into a usable shape but it will never quite perform as well as it should.  It is open source though so the adventurous might be able to make a more effective solution by modifying the source.

Comment: Wow. Wasn't expecting an answer that good after such a long time. Will give it a go....